# Why are there two different class diagrams in VS 2012 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, class-diagram

In Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, there are two class diagram document types:

1. `Class Diagram` (extension `.cd`)
2. `UML Class Diagram` (extension `.classdiagram`)

   - **Why are there two different class diagrams ?**
   - **What are the differences?**
   - **In what case should I use each?**

### Adding a class diagram to a code project

[image: Right-click on the code project in Solution Explorer->Add->New Item->General->Class Diagram]

### Adding an UML class diagram to a modeling project

First, creating a modeling project:
[image: Right-click on the solution in Solution Explorer->Add->New Project->Modeling Projects->Modeling Project]

Then adding the diagram to it:
[image: Right-click on the modeling project in Solution Explorer->Add->New Item->Modeling->UML Class Diagram]

### Differences

I noticed several differences:

- The looks are different
- Basic functionality is hidden in different menus or buttons
- I can't add an `UML Class Diagram` to a code project
- I can't add a `Class Diagram` to a modeling project
- I can add classes to a `Class Diagram` diagram directly from the solution explorer
- But to add classes to an `UML Class Diagram` from the solution explorer, I first have to drag'n'drop them onto a `Code Map`
- I can also add classes to an UML Class Diagram by dragging them from the Architecture Explorer (Architecture menu -> Windows -> Architecture Explorer)

[image]

Comment: @Hoh no, I know the difference between a Class Diagram and an Object Diagram, and both diagrams in Visual Studio are Class Diagrams (which begs my question: why two of them).